# HC-05 Stuck in slave loop mode (loopback)

Tags: hardware, hc-05

got my HC-05 today and accidently set the AT+ROLE=2(slave loop) and now I can't get out of it! Anything I send it just resends it back to me, even commands like AT+RESET and AT+ORGL, they just get returned. I can't figure out how to put the device back in slave mode, your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

H., you have to connect the module in the natural configuration mode to receive AT commands by default, which it is at 38400 Baud. Try sending AT with the arduino console (with carreturn and new line control). If this works then send AT+MODE=0.
Also, from here, you can send AT+ORGL to set original from factory. I usually use a CP2102 usb-serial interface with the hc-05 module, and the YAT serial terminal program from windows, because it is comfortable for me. Greetings. jvarl.